# How to save videos from You Tube?

Tags: youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Youtube and Google video downloaders ?](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-Google-video-downloaders)

I would like to save some videos I see in You Tube so that I could see them myself later on and also save pictures taken from those videos. Is that possible? Does it exist any free software or application that easily allows such video-photo captures?

Comment: Use [`youtube-dl` utility](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/).

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is done by way of browser plugins. Have a look around your browser of choice's extensions gallery.

You can also stream the video to [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and save it that way. See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9qaodFx3os) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dwhelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/) firefox plugin.  It works for many more sites than YouTube as well.